# How to set frame for TapGesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an imageview and I want to tap on only one side of imageview. Is it possible to set frame for a gesture? Can anyone help with a solution?

Comment: Just add a transparent view one side of the image view, then add gesture to that view...

Comment: welcome Sumi...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include more detail and to bring clarity to your question. You cannot set a frame for ant type of gesture, you add a gesture recognizer to a view object, you can then manipulate the frame of the view or test the location of the tap in the view that you added the tap gesture to.

Answer (score 3):

Use `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, i think you can get the idea on how to compare:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch locationInView:yourview].x < somePoint.x) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could overlay a view on top of the imageview and add the tap recognizer to this new view, something like this will make the left hand side of the image tapable

```
UIView tapView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width/2, imageView.frame.size.height)];

[imageView addSubView:tapView]

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                          action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[tapView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put UIView on top of your imageView with frame as per your requirement and put tap gesture on that UIView.

You can do this by storyboard / xib or by programmatically.

By programmatically, for example - you want to tap only within the area with width of 50 px of your imageView. For this:

```
    UIView *vw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imgView.frame.origin.x, imgView.frame.origin.y, 50, imgView.frame.size.height)];

    // add gesture to view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [vw addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    [imgView addSubview:vw];
```

now to handle your double tap

```
-(void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    // handle double tap
}
```